# How to keep my app running while it's minimized(maps)

Tags: android, service, maps

I have a class that shows the user path from the beginning of the trip until the end.If i minimize the app and open it to stop the trip recording it shows me one line from the start to the end of the trip not exactly the path i've taken.Here is the code

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

   //variables

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    List<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("Arrival");
    spinnerArray.add("Departure");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ardep);
    sItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    List<String> spinnerArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray2.add("Running");
    spinnerArray2.add("Walking");
    spinnerArray2.add("Cycling");
    spinnerArray2.add("Roller skating");
    spinnerArray2.add("Skateboarding");
    spinnerArray2.add("Kickbiking");
    spinnerArray2.add("Teleporting");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray2);

    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    actCombo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.actCombo);
    actCombo.setAdapter(adapter2);
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentHour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if (currentHour < 12) {
        actCombo.setSelection(GetInfo.arract - 1);
        sItems.setSelection(0);
    } else {
        actCombo.setSelection(GetInfo.depact - 1);
        sItems.setSelection(1);
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            3000,
            1, this);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    line = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.BLUE);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    fullnameside = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.fullnameside);
    emailside = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.emailside);
    fullnameside.setText("" + GetInfo.fullname);
    emailside.setText("" + GetInfo.email);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);

    //Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), ""+ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void getLocation() {
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "e paides", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    try {
        line.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        GMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title(""));
        GMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16.0f));
        steps++;
        getloc = true;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "gyhg" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void StopTrip(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Stop and upload your trip?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    float finalDistance = (float) (distance / 1000.0);
                    if (finalDistance < 2) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Map.this, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                    TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    // newActL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // startActL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    enabledActivity = false;
                    //database post
                    try {
                        Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        String formattedDate = df.format(currentTime);

                        Date currentTime2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss");
                        dateActEnd = df2.format(currentTime2);

                        String act = actCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String act_id = "7";
                        switch (act) {
                            case "Running":
                                act_id = "1";
                                break;
                            case "Walking":
                                act_id = "2";
                                break;
                            case "Cycling":
                                act_id = "3";
                                break;
                            case "Roller skating":
                                act_id = "4";
                                break;
                            case "Skateboarding":
                                act_id = "5";
                                break;
                            case "Kickbiking":
                                act_id = "6";
                                break;
                            case "Teleporting":
                                act_id = "7";
                                break;
                        }

                        String direcor;
                        if (sItems.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Arrival"))
                            direcor = "arrival";
                        else
                            direcor = "departure";

                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                        // String.format("%.1f", finalDistance)
                        URL obj = new URL("https://gekon.technologypark.cz/api/v1/record/create?user=" + LoginInfo.UserID
                                + "&date=" + formattedDate + "&distance=" + String.format("%.1f", finalDistance) + "&direction=" + direcor
                                + "&activity=" + act_id + "&polyline=" + PolyUtil.encode(line.getPoints()) + "&start=" + dateActStart
                                + "&end=" + dateActEnd + "&source=mobileapp");

                        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("ApiSecret", LoginInfo.ApiSecret);
                        conn.connect();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String output;
                        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null)
                            sb.append(output);

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                        JSONObject curRecord = new JSONObject(jsonObj.getString("data"));

                        Trips.datet.add(currentTime);
                        Trips.datestr.add(formattedDate);
                        Trips.act.add(act_id);
                        Trips.tripType.add(sItems.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        Trips.dist.add(String.format("%.1f", finalDistance));
                        Trips.trip_ids.add(curRecord.getString("trip_id"));
                        Trips.calc(++Trips.points);

                        TripsCalendarInfo.datet.add(currentTime);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.act.add(act_id);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.act_str.add(act);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.tripType.add(sItems.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        TripsCalendarInfo.dist.add(String.format("%.1f", finalDistance));
                        TripsCalendarInfo.datestr.add(formattedDate);
                        TripsCalendarInfo.trip_ids.add(curRecord.getString("trip_id"));
                        TripsCalendarInfo.trip_source.add("mobileapp");
                        TripsCalendarInfo.polyline.add(PolyUtil.encode(line.getPoints()));
                        TripsCalendarInfo.CanItrip();

                        float km_up = Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1)) + finalDistance;
                        int trip_up = Integer.parseInt(TripsInfo.trips.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1)) + 1;
                        TripsInfo.trips.set(TripsInfo.userRank - 1, "" + trip_up);
                        TripsInfo.km.set(TripsInfo.userRank - 1, String.format("%.1f", km_up));
                        TripsInfo.rankSort();

                        getloc = false;

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Map.this, Profile.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error upload, please check your options at gear button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    float finalDistance = (float) (distance / 1000.0);
    if (finalDistance < 2) {
        builder.setMessage("Your trip is below 2km and it will not be counted.\nAre you sure you want to stop?");
    }
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}


public void StartAct(View v) {
    timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dis.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    newActB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    stopActB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //gearMap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //headerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);          // to hide Navigation icon
    //toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    handler = new Handler();

    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd%20HH:mm:ss");
    dateActStart = df.format(currentTime);
    StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);

    startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
    //enabledActivity = true;
}

public void ChangeAct(View v) {
    if (newActL.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        newActL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startActL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        newActL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startActL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;

        UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;

        Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);

        Minutes = Seconds / 60;

        Hours = Minutes / 60;

        Seconds = Seconds % 60;

        Minutes = Minutes % 60;

        MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 100);

        timer.setText("Time: " + String.format("%02d", Hours) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", Minutes) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", Seconds));

        handler.postDelayed(this, 950);
    }

};

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    GMap = map;
    GMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(49.8117806, 15.6970293), 6.0f));
    if (!getloc)
        getLocation();
}
```

I tried [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-service-example/) but it didn't work.I believe that i somehow need to create a service and put all this code inside but i don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service would be a good fit here, **however**:
Starting from Android O some background limits were introduced:

- [Location](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) updates can only be received if your app either is in foreground, has a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) running or is used by another foreground app, like IME or a Notification listener.
- Background services now also have [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

Basically, for your purposes you can just move your location-based business-logic to a Service, start it as a foreground service (see [Context.startForegroundService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) and [Service.startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))) and show a [notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications), there's also an OK [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4) on that.
Although *not required*, it might be a good idea to let user stop your app's service or bring app to the foreground by interactiong with the notification, you can read more on this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Actions).

Note that Android P requires your app to hold the [FOREGROUND_SERVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#FOREGROUND_SERVICE) permission in order to start foreground services.

Also, you might want take a look at the [Geofencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing).

Comment: Nice links.  How about an edit with one for the notification?  Notification is the key for a high quality app that runs in background you need to let user know app is working and give user opportunity to turn off.

Comment: @danny117 sure, I'll try to add something

Answer (score 1):

To keep your app running you should create a service. If you do not create a service, Android will recognize your app as invasive and will try to close it.

Take a look to [Android Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Answer (score 1):

To show path from beginning to ending flow below steps.

- Create service (start in onCreate() of activity).
  Service will do start location tracking and stop location tracking.

onLocationChanged():- get all location coordinate and store somewhere.

Use this location coordinates to display paths.

- Stop service before activity destroy.